# Add external script and capture asychronous page evaluate result in Pyppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I am trying to use `page.evaluate` in Pyppeteer and capture JS script output but I am unable to capture it. In the following code, I am trying to capture the result returned by JS script in the `dimensions` variable, but it's capturing as `None`.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
async def hmm():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://jobs.chegg.com')
    dimensions = await page.evaluate("""async () => {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axe-core/3.1.2/axe.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        var result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axe.run(document, {
            runOnly: {
                type: "tag",
                values: ["wcag2a", "wcag2aa", "best-practice"]
            },
            "rules": {
                "skip-link": { enabled: false }
            }
            }, function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
                resolve(results);
            });
        });
        let test = await result.then((res) => {
            return res;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        
        console.log(test); 
        return test;
        }
    
    """)
    print(dimensions) # None
    return dimensions
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hmm())
```

Note: Open the console in any website and run the JS script, then an object/dictionary is returned.

Please suggest a solution for this problem.

Comment: Open console in any website i can't run the js script, or  the script inside """ """

Comment: the script only define a async function, haven't run it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you want to capture response from the site, you should listen to response. Here is an example with your site. It will print out every response object and related information.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

def interception_fun(response):
    # Response logic goes here
    print("URL:", response.url)
    print("Method:", response.request.method)
    print("Response headers:", response.headers)
    print("Request Headers:", response.request.headers)
    print("Response status:", response.status)
    return


async def hmm():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://jobs.chegg.com')
    page.on('response', interception_fun)
    
    await browser.close()

    return
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hmm())
```

**Update:**
As of pyppeteer version 0.2.5. `page.on()` should be lambda function like this:

`page.on('response', lambda res: asyncio.ensure_future(interception_fun(res)))`

Comment: this doesn't work when u want response.json()

Comment: @AbhishekKumar It works!
You have to make sure that response is a json. Like this - `if "application/json" in response.headers.get("content-type", ""):`
and then await response json like `r = await response.json()`. Now you have your json.

Comment: yes figured that `await` part later, now it works. thanks

Comment: pls [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879614/python-pyppeteer-intercept-capture-network-requests)

Comment: This isn't related to OP's request. OP's original post used the word "response" but they're really looking for the return value from the evaluate block. Clearly, OP wants to load the axe accessibility report library, generate a report and return it back to the Python process so they can programmatically use it. Intercepting network requests won't help them achieve this and is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Since loading an external script involves a network request, it's asynchronous. So trying to invoke `axe.run()` immediately after appending the script that loads `axe` won't work. You'll need to listen to the `onload` event on the script object before using `axe.run`.

The reason your code seems to work in the browser is probably because the axe library is cached, or the `axe` variable was already added to the page by you previously. When I run your code in a fresh tab, I get `ReferenceError: axe is not defined` on the first run, then it succeeds on the second run.

Here's a complete, runnable solution:

```py
# Python 3.10.12
import asyncio
import pyppeteer  # 1.0.2


async def run_axe(url):
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    report = await page.evaluate("""() => {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axe-core/3.1.2/axe.min.js";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          script.onerror = reject;
          script.onload = () => {
            axe.run(
              document,
              {
                runOnly: {
                  type: "tag",
                  values: ["wcag2a", "wcag2aa", "best-practice"]
                },
                "rules": {
                  "skip-link": { enabled: false }
                }
              },
              function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                  return reject(err);
                }

                resolve(results);
              }
            );
          }
        });
    }
    """)
    return report


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json

    url = "<Your URL>"
    report = asyncio.run(run_axe(url))
    print(json.dumps(report, indent=2))

    with open("axe-report.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(report, f)
```

The result JSON head looks like:

```js
{
  "violations": [
    {
      "id": "color-contrast",
      "impact": "serious",
      "tags": [
        "cat.color",
        "wcag2aa",
        "wcag143"
      ],
      "description": "Ensures the contrast between foreground and background colors meets WCAG 2 AA contrast ratio thresholds",
      "help": "Elements must have sufficient color contrast",
      "helpUrl": "https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/color-contrast?application=axeAPI",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "any": [
            {
              "id": "color-contrast",
// ...
```

You can also add a script tag from Pyppeteer using [`page.addScriptTag`](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.page.Page.addScriptTag).

If you want to run this headlessly (`pyppeteer.launch(headless=True)`), try using a non-robot user agent header:

```py
# ...
browser = await pyppeteer.launch(headless=True)
page = await browser.newPage()
ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
await page.setUserAgent(ua)
await page.goto(url)
# ...
```