# Python pyppeteer Intercept/Capture Network Requests

Tags: python, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, pyppeteer

Hi I am trying to intercept all the network calls for a given url using pyppeteer,

my code:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import pickle

async def interceptResponse(response):
    print("printing response")
    print(response)
    


async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=sun+flower&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN963IN963&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjboKfMkoj0AhURppUCHS9hAuMQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=486&dpr=1')
    new_resutls = page.on('response', 
        lambda response: asyncio.ensure_future(interceptResponse(response)))



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

the interceptResponse is getting **called only once, (i.e) for the very first network call, for any given url, I would like to capture all the network calls**, thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you defining `new_results` (you have also typo in there :) )?

Simply have `page.on('response', lambda response: asyncio.ensure_future(interceptResponse(response)))`

Comment: Pages can make network calls forever using AJAX, so "all the network calls" needs to be defined explicitly. What's your stopping condition? Do you want to keep going until a certain response is received, or the DOM is in a certain state, or for `n` seconds, or until `n` responses have arrived, or until no responses or requests have been created in the past `n` milliseconds ...? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

to main function for waiting for other requests